# Exception Unhandled... System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'... Please I've been stack at point for quiet long,

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

Please any help this is my final project I've been working on with a deadline... I've tried many solution but couldn't still resolve this...
Error appear on this line ***cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()***

```
conn.Open()
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into 
    Salestracker ( SDate, Waakye, Salad, 
    Gari, Spaghetti, Fish, Chicken, 
    Sausage, Egg, Beef, Water, WAmount
    Drink, DAmount, DrinksSold, 
    TotalCostOfMeal, TotalCostOfDelivery, 
    SubTotal, Tax, TotalAmount)Values('" + 
    lbldt.Text + "," + txtwaakye.Text + 
    "," +
    txtsalad.Text + "," + txtgari.Text + 
    "," + txtspag.Text + "," + 
    txtfish.Text + "," + txtchicken.Text + 
    "," + txtsausage.Text + "," +
    txtegg.Text + "," + txtbeef.Text + "," 
    + CmbWater.Text + "," + 
    txtWAmount.Text + "," + CmbDrink.Text 
    + "," + txtDAmount.Text + "," +
    txtDrinksSold.Text + "," + 
    txtTotalCostOfMeal.Text + "," + 
    txtTotalCostOfDelivery.Text + "," +
    txtSubTotal.Text + "," + txtTax.Text + 
     "," + txtTotalAmount.Text + "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Doesn't every string value have to be surrounded in single quotes and not the whole value array?

Comment: Thanks... But can you explain a little bit more... I don't get what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are creating a SQL command looking like this:

```sql
insert into
    Salestracker ( SDate, Waakye, Salad,
    Gari, Spaghetti, Fish, Chicken,
    Sausage, Egg, Beef, Water, WAmount
    Drink, DAmount, DrinksSold,
    TotalCostOfMeal, TotalCostOfDelivery,
    SubTotal, Tax, TotalAmount)Values('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,T,K,S,Q,L,M,N,O,P,R')
```

but the VALUES part should look like this

```sql
Values('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','T','K','S','Q','L','M','N','O','P','R')
```

i.e., each string in SQL must be enclosed in single quotes. Unless of course, when the column types are dates or numbers.

And there is a comma missing between the column names `WAmount` and `Drink`.

---

But using string concatenation to create a SQL command leads to several problems:

1. [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
2. Single quotes in texts must be escaped
3. Dates and times must be formatted the right way to be instered correctly into the DB. This is especially tricky with dates.

A better approach is to use parametrized queries:

```vb
conn.Open()
cmd = conn.CreateCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Salestracker ( SDate, Waakye, Salad, Gari, Spaghetti, Fish, Chicken, 
Sausage, Egg, Beef, Water, WAmount, Drink, DAmount, DrinksSold, TotalCostOfMeal, TotalCostOfDelivery, 
SubTotal, Tax, TotalAmount) VALUES (@dt, @waakye, @salad, @gari, @spag, @fish, @chicken,
@sausage, @egg, @beef, @water, @wAmount, @drink, @dAmount, @drinksSold, @totalCostOfMeal, @totalCostOfDelivery,
@subTotal, @tax, @totalAmount)"

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@dt", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = lbldt.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@waakye", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtwaakye.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@salad", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtsalad.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@gari", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtgari.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@spag", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtspag.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@fish", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtfish.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@chicken", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtchicken.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@sausage", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtsausage.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@egg", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtegg.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@beef", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtbeef.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@water", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = CmbWater.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@wAmount", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtWAmount.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@drink", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = CmbDrink.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@dAmount", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtDAmount.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@drinksSold", OleDbType.Integer)).Value = CInt(txtDrinksSold.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@totalCostOfMeal", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtTotalCostOfMeal.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@totalCostOfDelivery", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtTotalCostOfDelivery.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@subTotal", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtSubTotal.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@tax", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtTax.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@totalAmount", OleDbType.Double)).Value = CDbl(txtTotalAmount.Text)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

I don't know the types of your table columns. Therefore you might have do some adjustments to the code above.

Comment: Eg. Instead of   Values(A.text + "," + B.text... ) I now did Values( A.text + " ',' " + B.text...).  But still receive the same error message... And I correct the comma..

Comment: Or please I'm still wrong...

Comment: `"... VALUES ('" + A.text + "', '" + B.text + "', '" ...)`

Comment: Thank you soo much sir... For the data types... All are numbers expect Water and Drinks which are text.. And then Date which is Date/Time

Comment: Sir please the error has changed... It now displays... 'could not find output table ' Salestracker'. '

Comment: Thank you sir ones more.... It is solved now I was using the database name instead the Table name...

Answer (score 0):

Say you have field `name` of type string and field `amount` of type int. If you want to insert into table, your query would go like this: `insert into table_name (name, amount) values ('mark', 100)`. So, as you can see, only string field is surrounded by single quotes. In your example query would look like this `insert into table_name (name, amount) values ('mark, 100')` which is not valid.

Let's look at next example.
Say you have fields `name:String`, `age:int`, `country:String` and that you get values from `txtName`, `txtAge`, `txtCountry`.
Query to insert in table would look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into table_name (name, age, country) values ('" + txtName.Text + "', " + txtAge.Text + ", '" + txtCountry.Text + "')";
```

Much easier way would be using `$` before string which gives you option to pass variables directly to string with surrounding them with `{}`.
So this example would look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = $"insert into table_name (name, age, country) values ('{txtName.Text}', {txtAge.Text}, '{txtCountry.Text}')";
```

Comment: Sure thanks, but in my case I'm not trying to insert directly through the codes... I'm trying to tell the program that whatever I enter into those textboxes should be directed into the fields provided in Ms - Access

Comment: Or.. Pardon me if I'm still not understanding what you are trying to explain...